# "Cannot access memory" error when use GDB for TensorFlow compiled from sources

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, tensorflow

Hello All, 
I compiled a fresh TensorFlow sources with the debug option and tried to attach GDB to the Python process with imported TensorFlow in it.

When the `break TF_NewSession` was added in GDB, I got `Cannot access memory at address [...]`. 

What can be the issue here?

---

**Env**: *OS X Yosemite 10.10.4, gdb 7.10, GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53), Python 2.7.10*

**Details** on executed steps:

1. Compiled TensorFlow with **debug option**:

   ```
   $ bazel build -c dbg --strip=never //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
   ```
2. Prepared pip package:

   ```
   $ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
   ```
3. Created a Virtualenv environment and installed the package:

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/tensorflow
   $ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
   $ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
   (tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl
   ```
4. Run TF and attached to python process using gdb:

   ```
   #terminal 1:
   (tensorflow)$ python
   >>import tensorflow as tf
   >>import os
   >>os.getpid()
   10856

   #terminal 2:
   $ gdb -p 10856
   [...]
   (gdb) break TF_NewSession
   Cannot access memory at address 0x3d8fdd0  <-- ERROR
   ```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: One possible reason is that gdb failed to attach to the process. It would say so after printing its Copyright. If so, see if you have `ptrace_scope` enabled. Apparently there are also some "signed" binary issue -  https://github.com/dbenque/delveAppengine/issues/6